# Error in compile SDK version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Can anyone please tell me how do i fix this error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhishek.detector"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
}
```

Error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\hp-pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Did you tried with clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes a lot.........................

Comment: Try with Adding `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig`.

Comment: try @jaydroider suggestions

Comment: your support library version and compile sdk version must match.. Try to use API level 23 and update your compile sdk version and target sdk version.. otherwise use 21.*.* version for support libraries. Hope it will help :) Don't forget to vote up!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest version of the build tools. Adjust your `build.gradle` to use

```
`buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`
```

or check and remove duplicate dependencies from list.

Enjoy :)

Comment: i already did that , it remove the bug but when i open activity main or content main to design app it shoe another bug:: Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: i know its not a big deal but only when you see the design in my case i cant see the design too

Answer (score 1):

Change the sdk version from the values/string.xml